# Filtering Messages Handled By WearableListenerService

Tags: android, wear-os, android-wear-data-api

I have noticed that my `WearableListenerService` is started at random times by a connected watch even when it's not my app that has sent the message.

I know it's being started because when I leave it over night, I log when its created and it is started multiple times at random intervals over the course of the night. I also log when my `Application` class is created and it's at the same time.

I still want the service's functionality of being able to get called even when the application is closed however not all of the time.

Is there a way to only start my `WearableListenerService` when a message is sent from my Android Wear application?

Answer (score 1):

You can filter messages using code similar to the code below:

public class ListenerServiceFromWear extends WearableListenerService {

```
private static final String HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH = "/hello-world-wear";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(MessageEvent messageEvent) {

    /*
     * Receive the message from wear
     */
    if (messageEvent.getPath().equals(HELLO_WORLD_WEAR_PATH)) {

        Intent startIntent = new Intent(this, MyActivity.class);
        startIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(startIntent);
    }

}
```

}